# How to populate data for tests in spring data rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have a problem with unit testing spring data rest application with custom controller.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "channels")
public interface ChannelsRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Channel, Long> {
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "systems")
public interface SystemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<System, String>{
}



@RestController
public class SystemController {

    private String query = "select a.id as fromId, b.id as toId\n" +
            "from channel a, channel b\n" +
            "where ST_Distance_Spheroid(\n" +
            "\ta.coordinates,\n" +
            "\tb.coordinates,\n" +
            "\t'SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563]'\n" +
            ") <= :criticalDistance and a.id != b.id";

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Autowired
    private SystemRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value="systems/{systemId}/graph", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<BigInteger, List<BigInteger>> createNeighbourhsGraph(@PathVariable("systemId") String systemId,
                                                                    @RequestParam(value = "distance") double distance) {
        List<Object[]> results =  manager.createNativeQuery(query).setParameter("criticalDistance", distance).getResultList();
        Map<BigInteger, List<BigInteger>> map = new HashMap<BigInteger, List<BigInteger>>();
        for (Object[] result: results) {
            BigInteger fromId = (BigInteger) result[0];
            if (map.containsKey(fromId)) {
                map.get(fromId).add((BigInteger) result[1]);
            }
            else {
                List<BigInteger> neighbours = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
                map.put(fromId, new ArrayList<BigInteger>(Arrays.asList(new BigInteger[]{(BigInteger) result[1]})));
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

I've tried to populate data by posting it but without any luck. It seems that in unit test there haven't been created any mappings that are created when running application, so all I got is exceptions saying that there is no mapping to 'system/...' etc.

So as you can see I tried to populate data through repository. And it's not working also, probably some transaction issue, because I can see insert statements in logs, but there is nothing in the db.

I saw that I can provide some sql scripts to populate data, but this seems very stupid thing to do, because why do we have ORM then if we would still use SQL for a simple task like this.

```
    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        channels.System system = new System("foo");

        GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
        Channel[] channels = new Channel[]{
                new Channel(
                        1,
                        system,
                        gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(55.7565, 37.6153)),
                        1,
                        Arrays.asList(new String[]{"м. Охотный ряд"})
                ),
                new Channel(
                        1,
                        system,
                        gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(55.8079, 37.5808)),
                        1,
                        Arrays.asList(new String[]{"м. Дмитровская"})
                ),
                new Channel(
                        1,
                        system,
                        gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(50.4451, 30.5182)),
                        1,
                        Arrays.asList(new String[]{"м. Театральная"})
                ),

        };
        channelsRepository.save(Arrays.asList(channels));
        system.setChannels(Arrays.asList(channels));
        systemsRepository.save(system);
//        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
//        String systemAsJson = IOUtils.toString(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("system.json"));
//        String channelsAsJson = IOUtils.toString(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("channels.json"));
//        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
//        JSONObject system = (JSONObject) parser.parse(systemAsJson);
//
//        String result = mockMvc.perform(post("/systems")
//                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
//                        content(system.toJSONString())
//                        ).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
//        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: Have you had a look at `@Sql`?

Comment: See [this page](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html), it's for programmatically inserting data to a DB during tests.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't see changes in database because (in case you are using [AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/test/AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests.html)) spring cleans up transaction after test execution. So inside the test method data is available.
- Using of sql scripts is not stupid and may be suitable in many situations.
- Take a look at TestNG [ru](http://habrahabr.ru/post/121234/)

Comment: I don't see how to populate data in last link you gave. But anyway I've been able to appropriately build mockmvc so that resources are exported and now I can actually just post and delete data before and after test

Answer (score 0):

I've added webapplication contet and now I can post and remove data through perform(post()) and perform(delete) methods and I'm okay with it for now.

```
  @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private JSONArray channels;
    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
```